# Project parameter from SQL query into object

Tags: c#, dapper

I have the following query which is executed in C# using Dapper.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<UserDetails>> GetUsers(DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    try
    {
        const string query = @"SELECT UserName, ExecutedFromDate as @fromDate
                               FROM UserTable
                               WHERE TransactionDate >= @fromDate 
                                 AND TransactionDate <= @toDate";

        var result = await Connection.QueryAsync<UserDetails>(query, new { fromDate = from, toDate= to });
    }
}
```

I also have a POCO class:

```
public class UserDetails 
{ 
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExecutedFromDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime ExecutedToDate { get; set; }
}
```

As the `UserName` in the `UserDetails` is populated, I want the `ExecutedFromDate` and `ExecutedToDate` to hold the values of `to` and `from` from the parameters respectively. How can I achieve that? Please help.

Comment: Which tags am I missing?

Comment: I want to `ExecutedFromDate` to get the value of `from`

Comment: looked at this again, this `ExecutedFromDate as @fromDate` I don't think is correct. `@fromDate` is parameter but used as alias. Don't put alias

Comment: What do I put then ?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to/from in your object from the table or from the parameters you pass in?

Comment: I want it from my parameters that I have passed in

Comment: then try `SELECT UserName, @fromDate fromDate, @toDate toDate...`

Comment: @T.S.: It works bro. Put it as an answer. I'll mark this up bro. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your sql is incorrect.

```sql
SELECT UserName, ExecutedFromDate as @fromDate
```

Above, you use parameter as alias. If you want to return your input parameters as data from your query, do this

```sql
SELECT UserName, @fromDate fromDate, @toDate toDate...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your query to this:

```
const string query = @"SELECT UserName, 
                       @fromDate ExecutedFromDate,
                       @toDate ExecutedToDate
                       FROM UserTable
                       WHERE TransactionDate >= @fromDate 
                       AND TransactionDate <= @toDate";
```